# Kubernetes: VPN server and DNS issues

Tags: dns, docker, vpn, kubernetes

I spinned a [`docker-openvpn`](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn) container in my (local) **Kubernetes** cluster to access my Services securely and debug *dependent services* locally.

I can connect to the cluster via the **openVPN** server. However I can't resolve my **Services** via **DNS**.

I managed to get to the point where after setting routes on the VPN server:

- I can ping a **Pod** *by IP* (`subnet 10.2.0.0/16`)
- I can ping a **Service** *by IP* (`subnet 10.3.0.0/16` like the DNS which is at `10.3.0.10`)
- I can `curl` to a **Services** *by IP* and get the data I need.

but when i `nslookup kubernetes` or any **Service**, I get:

```
nslookup kubernetes
;; Got recursion not available from 10.3.0.10, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.3.0.10, trying next server
```

I am still missing something for the data to return from the DNS server, but can't figure what I need to do.

How do I debug this `SERVFAIL` issue in **Kubernetes DNS**?

**EDIT:**

Things I have noticed and am looking to understand:

- `nslookup` works to resolve Service name in any pod except the openvpn Pod
- while `nslookup` works in those other Pods, `ping` does not.
- similarly `traceroute` in those other Pods leads to the flannel layer `10.0.2.2` and then stops there.

from this I guess ICMP must be blocked at the flannel layer, and that doesn't help me figure where DNS is blocked.

**EDIT2:**

I finally figured how to get nslookup to work: I had to push the DNS search domain to the client with

```
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH cluster.local"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH svc.cluster.local"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH default.svc.cluster.local"
```

add with the `-p` option in the `docker-openvpn` image

so i end up with

```
docker run -v /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig \
-u udp://192.168.10.152:1194 \
-n 10.3.0.10 \
-n 192.168.10.1 \
-n 8.8.8.8 \
-n 75.75.75.75 \
-n 75.75.75.76 \
-s 10.8.0.0/24 \
-d \
-p "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "route 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH svc.cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH default.svc.cluster.local"
```

Now, `nslookup` works but **`curl` still does not**

Comment: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn describes creating configuration files and certificates in a docker-volume. How did you created configuration files and certificates, which would be valid for openvpn server running in a k8s-cluster? Then how did you mount those files in k8s-container? Using secrets?

Comment: sorry i never replied to this comment: I opened a PR to do this for k8s https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/pull/98 with all you need. This is old, and there is now other options like https://github.com/redspread/kube-openvpn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

finally my config looks like this:

```
docker run -v /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig \
-u udp://192.168.10.152:1194 \
-n 10.3.0.10 \
-n 192.168.10.1 \
-n 8.8.8.8 \
-n 75.75.75.75 \
-n 75.75.75.76 \
-s 10.8.0.0/24 \
-N \
-p "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "route 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH svc.cluster.local" \
-p "dhcp-option DOMAIN-SEARCH default.svc.cluster.local"
```

`-u` for the VPN server address and port

`-n` for all the DNS servers to use

`-s` to define the VPN subnet (as it defaults to 10.2.0.0 which is used by Kubernetes already)

`-d` to disable NAT

`-p` to push options to the client

`-N` to enable NAT: it seems critical for this setup on Kubernetes

the last part, pushing the search domains to the client, was the key to getting `nslookup` etc.. to work.

note that curl didn't work at first, but seems to start working after a few seconds. So it does work but it takes a bit of time for curl to be able to resolve.

Comment: Tested OpenVPN 2.3.12 on Ubuntu 15.10: Change the config from "DOMAIN-SEARCH" to "DOMAIN" (reference: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html)
Also run client on linux using an up script in linux clients. (something along this line: "openvpn --script-security 2 --up update-resolv-conf --config user.ovpn")

Comment: i use this script add openvpn in k8s cluster. thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try curl -4. Maybe it's resolving to the AAAA even if A is present.

Comment: not sure what the problem is with the delay, but curl actually works fine after say 5-10sec from connecting, with the original config.